# How to run two sql statements after each other in java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, arraylist

Sorry for my badly phrased question, but I have this ArrayList in a class, which I'm running from a main/menu class in another layer, but I only think you need to see this code to be able to help me.
Below I have two outputs: the first one shows what this ArrayList is printing out
the second one shows what I want it to look like.
What do I change in the ArrayList?

Keep in mind, I'm working in a three-layer architecture

```
public ArrayList<BEGroup> getGroupRankings() throws SQLException {
        ArrayList<BEGroup> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Statement stm2 = mConnection.createStatement();;
        stm2.execute("select * from [Group]");
        ResultSet res = stm2.getResultSet();
        int id = 0;
        while (res.next()) {
            System.out.println(res.getString("GroupName"));
            ++id;
            Statement stm = mConnection.createStatement();
            stm.execute("Select Team.School, MatchesPlayed, (GoalsFor-GoalsAgainst) as [Goal Difference], "
                    + "Points from GroupStandings INNER JOIN Team on Team.id = GroupStandings.TeamID "
                    + "where GroupStandings.GroupID = " + id + " "
                    + "order by GroupStandings.GroupID, Points desc, [Goal Difference] desc, GoalsFor desc ");
            ResultSet res2 = stm.getResultSet();
            while (res2.next()){
                String school = res2.getString("School");
                int matchesPlayed = res2.getInt("MatchesPlayed");
                int goalDifference = res2.getInt("Goal Difference");
                int points = res2.getInt("Points");
                result.add(new BEGroup(school, matchesPlayed, goalDifference, points));
        }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Output looks like this:                                     Want it to look like this:

```
Group A                              Group A                
Group B                              School 1:     0    2    33
School 1:     0    2    33           School 2:     7    -3    7
School 2:     7    -3    7           Group B
School 3:     3    4    3            School 3:     3    4    3
School 4:     2    3    2            School 4:     2    3    2
```

**EDIT:** Also, if I put return result; just above the current return result; at the ending, i almost get it (Only group A though, not the rest of the groups):

Output:

```
Group Rankings: 
Group A  
School 1:     0    2    33
School 2:     7    -3    7
School 3:     3    4    3
School 4:     2    3    2
```

Comment: Where did school 2 go? Typo?

Comment: @Todd Yes sorry, typo.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing, can you post the code (or some of it) for `BEGroup`. Does it have an ID associated with it or something to identify the group, or just the school?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. But my BEGroup has a lot of constructors, and I'm fairly certain it has an ID associated with it. (Would it even be able to print if it hadn't?)

Comment: Where do you print School rows? I see you print groups inside `getGroupRankings` and I guess you print school in function that calls `getGroupRankings`.

Comment: I print school rows in my Menu class in the Presentation layer. Would show you the code if you could let me know how to share it with you. Putting it in the Original Post would cluster it a bit, wouldn't it?

Comment: It might be useful for diagnosing the problem. I don't think the problem is in querying database. I think the root of the problem is that you print group names inside `getGroupRankings` and schools laters after `getGroupRankings` returns. But it's just a guess.

Comment: @NiematojakTomasz Thank you for pointing out the printing thing, completely overlooked that. Almost got it working now.